# validates_associated model with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, mongoid

I have the following validates_associated scenario

```
class Parent
  include Mongoid::Document
  validates_associated :son
  validates_associated :daughter
end
```

when i create a parent, either of son or daughter is only created not both.
Now my problem is, when i try to create parent with son, then validation fails due to daughter validation and vice versa.

Is there any way that i can validate only son when son parameters are posted or or validate only daughter when daughter parameters are posted

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply an :if option and test if the associated document exists:

```
class Parent
  include Mongoid::Document
  validates_associated :son, :if => Proc.new { |p| p.son.present? } 
  validates_associated :daughter, :if => Proc.new { |p| p.daughter.present? }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use an associated child object, which has an attribute (i.e. `gender`) if it's beeing a son or a daughter.

`Child` model (male or female, depending on value in `gender`):

```
class Child
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :gender, :type => Symbol
  # and more fields as you probably want
  embedded_in :parent, :inverse_of => :child
  # your validation code

  def son?
    gender == :male
  end
  def daughter?
    gender == :female
  end
end
```

will be Embedded in `Parent` model:

```
class Parent
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :child
  validates_associated :child
end
```

Comment: Actually this dosen't solve my problem.
Cant we validate the assocaited model if the fields from that model is supplied?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but now I don't understand what's your problem here? Why doesn't this solve your problem? What's wrong with this solution?

Comment: probably i think i  didn't get what you are trying to say.
A further more explanation might help.
Some structured rails code will be much better.
Thanks